# TWRequest leaking?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

Im using TWRequest in ios5 but Leaks is reporting a memory leak for TWRequest.

I'm doing something like this, am I going wrong somewhere?

```
TWRequest *postRequest = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/friendships/create.json"] parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"auser"  forKey:@"screen_name"] requestMethod:TWRequestMethodPOST];

 // Set the account used to post the tweet.
 [postRequest setAccount:twitterAccount];

 // Perform the request created above and create a handler block to handle the response.
 [postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
       NSString *output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"HTTP response status: %i", [urlResponse statusCode]];

       [TWRequest release];
 }];
```

Comment: I'm surprised this works:[TWRequest release]; Does Leaks tell you which line is leaking?

Comment: Any message that you can send to an instance of `NSObject` you can also send to a class. `[TWRequest release];` won't do anything but "works".

Comment: Run Analyze in Xcode, it will probably show the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to change `[TWRequest release];` to `[postRequest release];`